# Using URL Authorization with URL Rewrite in IIS 8

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, iis-8

I have a Wordpress site hosted on IIS 8, so it is using URL Rewrite.  I am trying to restrict access to a custom page using URL Authorization in IIS, but I think the rewrite is interfering.

Here is the snippet of my web.config

```
        <location path="cr-upload"> 
      <system.webServer>  
        <security>
            <authorization> 
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="myDomain\myGroup" />
            </authorization> 
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

cr-upload is the URL for the page.  Windows Integrated Authentication is enabled and working.  I have been successful in restricting access to a directory and to index.php (as a test) with this method, but I can't seem to restrict access to a page that is getting it's URL rewritten.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Move the rule

```
      <security>
        <authorization> 
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" roles="myDomain\myGroup" />
        </authorization> 
      </security>
```

Above the URL Rewrite rule you have in your web.config file.